# Android studio 4.1 Debug Breakpoint not working

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio latest version some breakpoints are not reached which is placed under the implementation like DatePickerDialog ->onDateSet this one is just for the example wherever we implement the interfaces breakpoints no working in those places. Now breakpoints only working in *UI thread only*. Is that a new feature from the Android studio? If so I think I have to find a different IDE. Anyone else facing the same issue?

I reported an issue here also. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170920692

Comment: I have had this same issue the way I got around it was to just reinstall android 4.0 and just use that until the bugs have been fixed in 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated 4.1.1 now it's working fine.